# dynamic table saving in db using checkboxes php mysql

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have the following table to be saved to the DB. the $varline is a counter, used to total up the row values.

```
<table id="table1" border="1">
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>id</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Qty</th>
            <th>Select</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>A1</td>
            <td><input type="text" value="$id" name='item[$varline][id]'></td>
            <td><input type="text" value="$price" name='item[$varline][price]'></td>
            <td><input type="text" name='item[$varline][quantity]'></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="item[$varline][check-tab1]"></td>
        </tr>


        </tbody>

    </table>
```

I need to save the data to the DB using POST method...I am using the following javascript to calculate the totals:

```
function calcTot(i){

        unitPrice = document.getElementById("myTable").rows[i].cells[1].childNodes[0].value;
        quantity = document.getElementById("myTable").rows[i].cells[2].childNodes[0].value;
        amount= parseFloat(price) * parseFloat(quantity);
        document.getElementById("myTable").rows[i].cells[3].childNodes[0].value = amount.toFixed(2);
    }
```

The PHP code that I have constructed so far is given below:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$reservation_id = $_POST['res_id'];
$item_id = $_POST['item']['product_id'];
$item_quantity = $_POST['item']['quantity'];
$item_discount = $_POST['item']['discount'];
$item_unit_price = $_POST['item']['price'];
$item_amount = $_POST['item']['amount'];
$items_total = $_POST['item']['total'];
$items_checked = $_POST['checked_pro'];
$invoiceId = $_POST['invoice_id'];
foreach ($item_id as $key => $value) {
    $check_item_id = "SELECT item_id from products where item_id='" . $conn->real_escape_string($item_id[$key]) . "'LIMIT 1"; //check if item exist
    $resultset = $conn->query($check_item_id);
    if ($resultset->num_rows == 0) {
        $insert_product = "INSERT INTO `invoice_items` (`id`, `invoice_id`, `product_id`, `quantity`, `price`, `amount`) VALUES (NULL, '" . $conn->real_escape_string($invoiceId) . "', '" . $conn->real_escape_string($item_id) . "', '" . $conn->real_escape_string($item_quantity) . "', '" . $conn->real_escape_string($item_unit_price) . "', '" . $conn->real_escape_string($item_amount) . "')";
        $insert_item = mysqli_query($conn, $insert_product);
        if (!$insert_item) {

            echo "<script>";
            echo "alert('Error inserting!')";
            echo "</script>";
        }
```

}

Comment: where is the php code

Comment: do you expect us to write the php code? You know that's not going to happen. so try something

Comment: Sorry, I have included the script...I am running in to errors and my thesis deadline is tomorrow...thx